# How to get Program Files on Windows 64 bit in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, environment, program-files

Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles and Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86 returning x86
my pc is 64 bit
[image]
[image]

so how to get Program Files on Windows 64 in vb.net or #c

```
 Dim ProgramFiles As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
 Dim ProgramFilesX86 As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

Comment: Uncheck `Prefer 32-bit`.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is standard users do no have write access to the program files folder by default. It's no longer the correct place to keep data for your program, and hasn't been since at least 2004.

Comment: ok but if i Uncheck Prefer 32-bit will work on pc 64 bit only ??
because some people still use pc 32 bit to this time

Comment: No, it can still work on both types. That's what the "Any CPU" option is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProgramFilesX86` will always return the `Program Files (x86)` folder path while `ProgramFiles` will return the same path if your app is running in a 32-bit process and the `Program Files` folder path if your app is running in a 64-bit process.

If you target the x86 platform then your app will always run in a 32-bit process, meaning that it won't run on an OS that doesn't support 32-bit processes.

If you target the x64 platform then your app will always run in a 64-bit process, meaning that it won't run on an OS that doesn't support 64-bit processes.

If you target the AnyCPU platform and check the `Prefer 32-bit` box then your app will run in a 32-bit process if it can, otherwise it will run in a 64-bit process.

If you target the AnyCPU platform and uncheck the `Prefer 32-bit` box then your app will run in a 64-bit process if it can, otherwise it will run in a 32-bit process.

Your app would have been running in a 32-bit process because you checked the `Prefer 32-bit` box - note that it is checked by default - so your app could only see the `Program Files (x86)` folder, regardless of the OS. It doesn't make sense for 32-bit apps to do anything related to 64-bit processes.

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations
but if i Uncheck Prefer 32-bit will work on pc 64 bit only ?? because some people still use pc 32 bit to this time

Comment: Your question is already answered above.